# Account deleted move all posts from that account to default admin account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

first of thank you all for taking the time reading this and answering.

i'm trying to find example or at least some help with the logic,

what i'm trying to do, is after a user removes his/her account to automatically transfer any resources to default admin account.

Using devise for user management.

Not sure what you might need to know more on this to be able to help out, But let me know and i shall provide more information.

Thank you in advance!

Update: (so in my user.rb model i have added this and the before_destroy)

It only returns me to 404 error..

```
def transfert_associations_to_default_account
 #This user is the one ending account
 leavinguser = current_user.username

 #This will be the default user (archive) holder for all the content
 default_user = User.find_by(username: "archive")

 #default_user.resources << resources if default_user
leavinguser.posts.update(username: default_user)
leavinguser.reviews.update(username: default_user)
end
```

Update 2: (fixed)

```
def transfert_associations_to_default_account
 #This user is the one ending account
 leavinguser = self

 #This will be the default user (archive) holder for all the content
 default_user = User.find_by(username: "archive")

 default_user.posts << leavinguser.posts
 default_user.reviews << leavinguser.reviews
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a before_destroy | before_update action (depending of your logic) on the user model, like this

```
before_destroy :transfert_associations_to_default_account

def transfert_associations_to_default_account
 default_user = User.find()
 default_user.resources << resources if default_user
end
```

Comment: Hey thanks for fast response! can i trouble you for a more in-depth explanation to this part: default_user.resources = resources if default_user

Comment: develop _what i'm trying to do, is after a user removes his/her account to automatically transfer any resources to default admin account._ I don t which resources you want to tranfert

Comment: each users have posts and reviews etc that are bound to the user this is what i would like to transfer to the default admin user if the account is deleted.

Comment: lets do 

`posts.update_all(user_id: default_user)`
`reviews.update_all(user_id: default_user)`
... 

inside the method

Comment: I have updated with latest code, have yet to see why it's not working the issue at the moment with the code is that it returns 404 error. i'm not sure if it's because it's in the user.rb model file and should be somewhere else but i have not generated controller files for devise.

Comment: Solved it on update 2, not sure if this is the best way to go about doing this.
If you you have any comments on the update 2 please do let me know.

Comment: Hi, yeah that s better, you should set default_user = User.find_by(username: "archive") - 'archive' in a setting file. Better reusability

Comment: How would i go about setting up a setting file?

Comment: declare a yml file with what ever you need inside :)

Comment: ohh doh i thought it was some other way but yeah thanks will do that :)
i might just add it to seeds.rb and just run seed command when ever it's needed :) anyhow thanks again!